# How to change tag name in json structure of a generated model

Tags: go, gql

I have this **auto generated** model from GraphQL type

```
type Book struct {
    ID             string           `json:"id"`
    Title          string           `json:"title"`
    Description    string           `json:"description"`
    Category       string           `json:"category"`
}
```

I need to Unmarshal a payload into Book structure looking like this:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "title": "Some-title",
  "description": "description",
  "categoryName": "Fiction"
}
```

How can I change the tag **"categoryName"** of the payload coming from another BE source and Unmarshal into book structure?
Also, making a copy of this structure is not desirable as the actual Book object is large. Any advice will be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can use reflection to create a temporary struct with identical underlying type but with the tags replaced, then use pointer conversion (also utilizing `reflect`) and unmarshal the JSON into that. Something like this: https://go.dev/play/p/QGi4Emgz5c5 (the example in playground is naive, do not use it, instead write something proper).

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the structure, simply change the field from
`Category` to `CategoryName`

Assuming you don't have control over the book structure,
You have 3 options
a) Create an anonymous struct bucket to hold the json data.

```
var temp = struct{  
    ID             string           `json:"id"`  
    Title          string           `json:"title"`  
    Description    string           `json:"description"`  
    Category       string           `json:"categoryName"`   
}

Unmarshal(&temp)
```

This is the best option if you don't need these structures regularly and  the fields you need from a huge structure like `Book` keeps changing.

b) Use reflection to change the struct tag (Not advised)

c) Create another structure for unmarshalling the data and name it **BookDTO**