# How to set new tag value of nested struct using reflection

Tags: go, reflection

I have this structures:

```
type Library struct {
    Book            Book           
    Owner           Owner           
    Editorial.       Editorial
}

type Book struct {
    ID             string           `json:"id"`
    Title          string           `json:"title"`
    Description    string           `json:"description"`
    Category       string           `json:"category"`
}
```

My code changes the json tag of the Book structure (autogenerated). How can I assign the new tag value ("categoryID") to the final structure, as in order to set new value I had to create a new variable "sub". How can I assign "**sub**" to  **f** ?

```
func renameTags(p interface{}) any {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(p)
    rt := rv.Elem().Type()
    fields := make([]reflect.StructField, rt.NumField())
    for i := range fields {
        f := rt.Field(i)
        if f.Type.Kind() == reflect.Struct && f.Type.Name() == "Book" {
            sub := f.Type.Field(13)
            sub.Tag = reflect.StructTag(`json:"` + "categoryID" + `"`)
            
        }

        fields[i] = f
    }

    st := reflect.ValueOf(fields)
    x := st.Interface()
    return x 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are asking how to modify an existing struct type's struct-tags, then the answer is you cannot. Struct tags are part of the struct type, and Go is statically typed, which means you cannot change the struct type, nor its tags, at runtime.

Comment: it's related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75246468/how-to-change-tag-name-in-json-structure-of-a-generated-model/75251205#75251205 from your replay I assumed it was possible @mkopriva is it not?

Comment: What's the difference between this question and your previous one?

Comment: @mrTarragona no it's not possible. In my comment to your previous question a whole new type was created, a type separate from `Book`. The only thing the new type had in common with `Book` is that their [underlying types](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Underlying_types) were identical, and because of this property a value of the new type can be **converted** to a value of `Book` and vice versa. However none of this affects the `Book` *type* itself, none of this changes anything about the type as it was defined in code, before the program was compiled and executed. You can't change `Book` *the type*.